# creating a timer function

Tags: javascript, timer, p5.js

to explain the whole program as it is now: there are 6 tracks. I have speech recognition running where user speech is detected and when he speaks the first track is played fully and stopped when the track is over. then it starts listening for speech and when it is detected the second track plays so on until track 6.

what i want to change: is have the first track play.. wait for user speech response and if no response after 5 seconds play next track. but if user response is detected then go to next track immediately.

```
function parseResult() {
    var mostrecentword = myRec.resultString.split(' ').pop();
        if (mostrecentword.indexOf("") !== -1) {
            setInterval(myTimer, 1);
            songs[currentSong].playMode('untilDone');
            songs[currentSong].play();
            background(0, 255, 0);
        }
}


function myTimer() {
    if (millis() > startT + fiveSeconds) {
        startT = millis();
        console.log(startT);
        currentSong++;
        background(0, 0, 255);
    }

}
```

there is nothing in function draw() its empty.

```
function setup() {
    frameRate(1);
    createCanvas(600, 600);
    background(255, 255, 255);
    fill(0, 0, 0, 255);
    myRec.start();
    startT = millis();
}
```

and thats the setup. im using https://github.com/IDMNYU/p5.js-speech for speech recog (this part works great, no trouble at all)

Answer (score 0):

```
let currentSongIndex = 0
let totalSongs = 6
let canPlay = true
let timer = null

function playSong() {
    if (timer) {
        clearTimeout(timer)
        timer = null
    }

    songs[currentSongIndex].play()
    timer = setTimeout(nextSong, 5000)
}

function nextSong() {
    if (currentSongIndex < totalSongs) {
        currentSongIndex++
    }else{
        currentSongIndex = 0
    }

    playSong()
}


function speechResult() {
    var resultArray = myRec.resultString.split(' ').pop()

    if (resultArray.indexOf('') > -1 && canPlay) {
        nextSong()
    }
}
```

got an answer from @lassekorsgaard